# Cannot install web agent for openam due to missing dll libraries from openssl

Tags: windows-7, openssl, xampp, openam

When following the tutorial to install openAM, one of the steps is to create a web agent using the command

```
agentadmin.exe --i
```

But I get stuck on the second step:

```
Configuration file [c:\Apache\conf\httpd.conf]: c:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf
init_ssl(): ssleay32.dll is not available (error: 193)
init_ssl(): libeay32.dll is not available (error: 193)
```

I've tried downloading openssl from gnuwin32, also from slproweb, with or without placing those files inside `\web_agents\apache24_agent\lib`. Even looking on another web I found that I should replace `ssleay32.dll`, `libeay32.dll` and `openssl.exe` from `\xampp\apache\bin` and I did that.

The "Troubleshooting" section of openAM asks for installing KB2533623 , but when I try to install it from the .msu my system says that this is already installed.

All without success.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: Thanks for the links @jww. It is always a mistery to me how to decide if a question is on|off topic. Funnily enough the answer to the meta post you provide that has more reputation ends with: "DevOps questions should be allowed on Stack Overflow."

Comment: You may have a read of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18.aspx

Comment: Thanks @BernhardThalmayr, just in case I just did a `PATH=%PATH%;C:\web_agents\apache24_agent\lib` but with no changes. Maybe I'm missing something, Could you please elaborate a little bit further?

Answer (score 0):

Try patching [KB2758857](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/ms12-081.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) since it replaces KB2533623. Also, just to ensure it isn't a PATH issue with the user you're logged in as, find those two OpenSSL dll's and copy them to your system folder (c:\windows\system32) [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18.aspx]. Last, I would be sure you're using the latest OpenAM Web Policy Agent [4.0.0].

Comment: Thanks, However KB2758857 also says that this is already installed when I try to install it from the .msu , regarding the path issue, when I do a `where ssleay32.dll` it says `C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\ssleay32.dll` (and yes, I've been using 4.0.0 the whole time, actually a 4.0.1 version exists but that is "subscription only")

Comment: Placing the dll's on system32: Now `where ssleay32.dll` responds `C:\Windows\System32\ssleay32.dll` but `agentadmin --i` still says `init_ssl(): ssleay32.dll is not available (error: 193)
init_ssl(): libeay32.dll is not available (error: 193)` Anyway, thanks for your help, I'm going to award the bounty to you because at least you paid attention to my question ^_^'